# Android take argument open file

Tags: android, arguments

Looking for a way to get path of file (and then process it in app) associated with my Android application when user click on it from the file explorer.

Example: built-in media player opens .mp3 file when you click on selected file in the file explorer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an `<intent-filter>` to your activity supporting the `VIEW` action and the appropriate MIME type and/or file extension, such as this one from [the AOSP Music app](https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_music/blob/master/AndroidManifest.xml):

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:scheme="file"/>
            <data android:mimeType="audio/*"/>
            <data android:mimeType="application/ogg"/>
            <data android:mimeType="application/x-ogg"/>
            <data android:mimeType="application/itunes"/>
        </intent-filter>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it's definitely I was looking for!
Also would like to make accent to AOSP example: getting URI of resource you are going to process by intent.getData() – here is the way to process filepath in your app.

Comment: Another interesting thing here is that with  `android:launchMode="singleInstance"` you cant get filepath from intent.getData()